# Minecraft program frame rate is very slow

Tags: minecraft

I have recently downloaded Minecraft to Ubuntu 12.04. It launches and plays successfully, however- the frame rates for the game are extremely slow. They never go past 9 fps and usually drop below 3 fps.

I have been a Windows XP user for years and have just recently switched to Ubuntu, so I'm not an expert with this OS. My video card is a Diamond Stealth s60 with Radeon 7000.

I don't know what other information you guys need but if you ask for it, and would please tell me how to get to it, I will tell you as soon as I can. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Please also include your processor information, how much system ram you have, what version of Java, is it OpenJDK or Sun Java?

Answer (score 2):

[Minecraft Wiki: Hardware Performance](http://www.minecraftwiki.net/wiki/Hardware_performance)
    Any computer with the following hardware should suffice, however, for an enjoyable experience, we suggest looking at the recommended requirements.

```
Minimum requirements:
```

> ```
>     CPU : Intel P4/NetBurst architecture or its AMD equivalent (AMD K7)
>     RAM : 800MB
>     GPU : GeForce3 or ATI Radeon 7xxx and up.
>     HDD : At least 10MB for game data
>     Java Runtime Environment (JRE) 5 or up is required to be able to run the game.
> ```

```
Recommended requirements:
```

> ```
>     CPU : Intel Pentium D or AMD Athlon 64 (K8) 2.6 GHz
>     RAM : 2GB
>     GPU : GeForce 6xxx or ATI Radeon 9xxx and up with OpenGL 2.0 support (excluding integrated chipsets)
>     HDD : 150MB
> ```

Your Diamond Stealth s60 with Radeon 7000 is at the absolute bottom end of the minimum requirements for Minecraft. Compare your system with the other requirements and see if you may be falling short there as well. 
My recommendation to you would be to launch Minecraft and click "Options" and then "Video Settings". Reduce all settings to the minimums and then run the game to check for improvement. If you still experience low FPS you may need to upgrade your hardware.

Comment: All of the requirements have been met to the recommended requirements- except the graphics card of course.However, Sysinfo says that my CPU is an AMD Athlon 64 Processor 3500+. My previous OS was 32 bit, so I downloaded the 32 bit Ubuntu. Should I have downloaded the 64 bit version, and would this have caused fps problem?

Comment: Your processor is a very early 64 bit cpu so then should be able to use 64 bit version of Ubuntu. The benefits to you of switching may be negligible and I don't believe that to be the source of your fps issue. Your hardware is at the low end of the requirements. Aside from upgrading my last recommendation to you would be to launch Minecraft and click "Options" and then "Video Settings". Reduce all settings to the minimums and then run the game to check for improvement.

Comment: Okay thank you, now that I know that it's just the graphics card I plan on buying a better one.

Comment: @Cade I saw in my research that your current card is a PCI slot card. Check your computer/motherboard specs to see if it has an AGP slot. AGP (Accelerated Graphics Port) was a specialized slot meant solely for graphics cards. As such it will offer better performance than a PCI card of the same model and specs. AGP and PCI have now been replaced by PCI Express (PCIe). This means that you will not be able to find recent cards but you will be able to find a card that will play Minecraft.

Comment: @Cade If you found this answer helpful, please accept it so the question may be closed. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you are talking about this card:

[ATI - S60PC](http://www.diamondmm.com/S60PCI64.php)

If so I think this is not really a very powerful card. But still you might have some options. If I am right you are using the card without any manual system changes.

So you could try the following to change the driver to a prorietary one:

[Install Catalyst](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BinaryDriverHowto/ATI)

Advantage: Faster - ((but proprietary))

Disadvantage: If the driver is compiled to your momentary kernel - you will have do recompile your driver again as soon as your kernel is changed cuz of updates.

But be warned as it is written here:

> WARNING: Using a method other than described in the manual instructions section above by creating a .deb file can lead to extreme difficulties. Be sure to take note of the instructions for uninstalling the driver at the end of this section, since the driver must be uninstalled using the amdconfig utility.

Cuz if the driver is NOT working for you - you have to get rid of him again. Otherwise you might have no screen at all.

Good luck - and others managed it so you can do as well.

Answer (score 0):

GO to video settings, disable particles, smooth lighting, clods smooth lighting. done.